# Remove X and Y axis from PyKrige result

Tags: python, kriging

I am trying to use the `PyKrige` module in Python to interpolate via `Ordinary Kriging` my XYZ dataset.

I have the below script, code taken from https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mZDVJ-RioBc4QHHpe2HBNJrx8sJ4-1Lw?pli=1#scrollTo=6OfzYklg_Db1

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd


x1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test_file.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')
y1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test_file.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')
z1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test_file.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')

x = list(x1)
y = list(y1)
z = list(z1)

cax = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, fraction=0.03)
plt.title('DensA Points')


OK = OrdinaryKriging(
    x, 
    y, 
    z, 
    variogram_model='gaussian',
    verbose=True,
    enable_plotting=False,
    nlags=5,
)

OK.variogram_model_parameters

gridx = np.arange(626000, 629100, 5, dtype='float32')
gridy = np.arange(231500, 234500, 5, dtype='float32')
zstar, ss = OK.execute("grid", gridx, gridy)

print(zstar.shape)
print(ss.shape)

cax = plt.imshow(zstar, extent=(626000, 629100, 231500, 234500), origin='lower')
savefig( 'C:/users/public/test.tiff' )
print('image saved')
```

The code works, but my issue is the X and Y axis.

I only want the interpolated tiff image so that I can bring it into QGIS etc. However, the output is giving me an X and Y axis, and I'm not sure how to remove them without breaking the code.

Comment: Your script, save result as a matplotlib image, while PyKrige allows you to save the result as an [ASCII grid file (*.asc).](https://geostat-framework.readthedocs.io/projects/pykrige/en/stable/generated/pykrige.kriging_tools.write_asc_grid.html?highlight=asc%20) which can be used in QGIS

Comment: you can try : plt.axis('off') in your code, this should tell pyplot to not show the axis. however another format could be a better idea as @gene say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `kt.write_asc_grid()` which will create a .asc file you can import in QGIS

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pylab import *
import pandas as pd


x1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test_file.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')
y1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test_file.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')
z1 = np.loadtxt("c:/test_file.xyz", usecols=0, dtype='float')

x = list(x1)
y = list(y1)
z = list(z1)

cax = plt.scatter(x, y, c=z)
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax, fraction=0.03)
plt.title('DensA Points')


OK = OrdinaryKriging(
    x, 
    y, 
    z, 
    variogram_model='gaussian',
    verbose=True,
    enable_plotting=False,
    nlags=5,
)

OK.variogram_model_parameters

gridx = np.arange(626000, 629100, 5, dtype='float32')
gridy = np.arange(231500, 234500, 5, dtype='float32')
zstar, ss = OK.execute("grid", gridx, gridy)

print(zstar.shape)
print(ss.shape)

kt.write_asc_grid(gridx, gridy, zstar, filename="output.asc")
```